# NumberFormatter inconsistency with Float and Double values

Tags: swift, floating-point, number-formatting

I came across a **different behavior of NumberFormatter when using Float and Double values**. Specifically, when applying the **"halfUp" roundingMode**, NumberFormatter returns different rounded string values for the same number when using Float and Double value types. The problem is illustrated below.

*XCode 14.2 Playground*

```
import Cocoa

let decimalHalfUpFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.roundingMode = .halfUp
    return formatter
}()

extension FloatingPoint {
    var halfUpFormatted: String {
        return decimalHalfUpFormatter.string(for: self) ?? "n/a"
    }
}

print(Double(1.625).halfUpFormatted) // prints 1.63 (correct)
print(Double(1.635).halfUpFormatted) // prints 1.64 (correct)

print(Float(1.625).halfUpFormatted) // prints 1.63 (correct)
print(Float(1.635).halfUpFormatted) // prints 1.63 <- why isn't it 1.64 using Float?
```

As you can see, the same number (1.635) is rounded differently when using Float and Double. Why does this happen?

**Is this related to the lower precision of Float types compared to Double, or does the NumberFormatter's rounding mode work differently for various value types?**

*I understand that decimal numbers are a complex topic, which is why I use NumberFormatter for displaying number values. However, I'm surprised that even NumberFormatter appears to be inconsistent when working with floating-point numbers.*

Comment: I suffered from this for long when working on a Simulator. This is primarily because of the way they are handled in the memory. Though both are IEEE standards, `float` is a 32bit single precision & `double` is 64bit Double precision `type`. Inside, the numbers are actually not what you see  or what you passed but close to that number. So when rounding off, the output varies. If you increase the number of precision points & compare using `print`/ `debug`/`console`, you will understand the reasons and difference.

Comment: @Hollycene, Try printing `1.635` with at least 20 significant digits.  What do you get?

Comment: If you care about fraction digits precision you should be working with Swift Decimal instead of double. Make sure to do NOT use a FloatingPoint literal when initializing it

Comment: *"Is this related to the lower precision of Float types compared to Double"* - Yes. When printed to 20 decimal places, Double(1.635) == 1.63500000000000000888. Float(1.635) == 1.63499999046325683594.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. @HangarRash's comment answered the question perfectly. I didn't think about using more significant digits, as "chux - Reinstate Monica" suggested. Now I see the reason for the difference. Thank you all!